# Hamburger menu indication does not show up in toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am working on what is really my first Android app and am having issues making the hamburger menu indicator/button display on the top left. Despite the lack of the icon, swiping left in the app will open the navigation drawer. What's missing?

The toolbar.xml file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark">
```

The MainActivity.class

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.view.View;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private NavigationView nvDrawer;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle drawerToggle;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set a Toolbar to replace the ActionBar.
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Find our drawer view
        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        nvDrawer = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nvView);
        // Setup drawer view
        setupDrawerContent(nvDrawer);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // Find our drawer view
        mDrawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawerToggle = setupDrawerToggle();

        // Tie DrawerLayout events to the ActionBarToggle
        mDrawer.addDrawerListener(drawerToggle);

    }
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle setupDrawerToggle() {
        return new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawer, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,  R.string.drawer_close);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // The action bar home/up action should open or close the drawer.
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case android.R.id.home:
                mDrawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    // `onPostCreate` called when activity start-up is complete after `onStart()`
    // NOTE! Make sure to override the method with only a single `Bundle` argument
    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    private void setupDrawerContent(NavigationView navigationView) {
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {
                        selectDrawerItem(menuItem);
                        return true;
                    }
                });
    }

    public void selectDrawerItem(MenuItem menuItem) {
        // Create a new fragment and specify the fragment to show based on nav item clicked
        Fragment fragment = null;
        Class fragmentClass;
        switch(menuItem.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.nav_first_fragment:
                fragmentClass = CompareFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_second_fragment:
                fragmentClass = BuildFragment.class;
                break;
            case R.id.nav_third_fragment:
                fragmentClass = VideosFragment.class;
                break;
            default:
                fragmentClass = CompareFragment.class;
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        // Insert the fragment by replacing any existing fragment
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();

        // Highlight the selected item has been done by NavigationView
        menuItem.setChecked(true);
        // Set action bar title
        setTitle(menuItem.getTitle());
        // Close the navigation drawer
        mDrawer.closeDrawers();
    }
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Class fragmentClass;
        Fragment fragment = null;
        final int id = v.getId();
        switch (id) {

            default:
                fragmentClass = CompareFragment.class;
                break;
        }

        try {
            fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.flContent, fragment).commit();
    }

}
```

The styles.xml:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorPrimary">#3F51B5</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#303F9F</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#FF4081</item>
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>

    </style>
    <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />
    <style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark" />

    <style name="DrawerArrowStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.DrawerArrowToggle">
        <item name="spinBars">true</item>
        <item name="color">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

For adding this toolbar, I have mostly been following an online tutorial, as I do not quite understand toolbars quite yet. Let me know if anything else is needed. I appreciate any help that can be provided!

Comment: You need to call `syncState()` on the toggle after the setup.

Comment: Mike M., you were completely right. Thank you so much! And, yeah, it does seem to be a duplicate from a post I overlooked.

Comment: No problem. I would mention that you probably wanna call that in the `onPostCreate()` method, to make sure it works with all configuration changes and what not. You've already got that method there; you might've just missed it in the tutorial. You should be able to mark that post as helpful, or something to that effect, to close out your question now. Cheers!